# Data not present in excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, excel-2010, openpyxl

I'm  reading a existing excel file by using openpyxl package and trying to save that file it, and it got saved but after opening that excel file no data is present. I used the following code and my requirement is to open the file in `use_iterators = True` mode only

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'large_file.xlsx', use_iterators = True)

ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'big_data') 

for row in ws.iter_rows():

    for cell in row:

        print cell.internal_value

wb.save("large_file.xlsx")
```

can u guys show how to save the file and close the file after saving with out losing the data

Answer (score 2):

Try loading with `use_iterators = False`, as `use_iterators = True` loads the data information differently, such that it may not contain all the information you wish to save.

Openpyxl writes and entirely new excel file based on the information it has read in, so it's not like you make a small change and just update the file.  (This also means if certain features aren't supported in openpyxl (such as VB macros), these won't exist in the file you've saved.)

Comment: hi..adam, when iam trying to load the excel file by using use_iterators = False , excel file is not saving and its not responding it taking so much time and dint showing any error message because my excel file is large in size, so i choose use_iterators = True ..can u show me a solution for this